# Is it possible to use PEX with C?

Tags: c++, c, pex

I'm new to PEX, Visual Studio and the .NET world, neverthless I
generated a few tests for C#. I have read, that PEX can also analyze
.NET programs written in any .NET language, so at the moment I am
trying to get PEX working with C (I have stored the code in a C++
project. Is this the right approach?). Since there is no Visual Studio
PEX add-in for C++, I tried using the command line interface.
In the tutorial "Parameterized Unit Testing with Microsoft Pex" it
says, that I should have a ".NET assembly" ending with .dll or .exe
that contains a class annotated with the PexClassAttribute and public
method annotated with the PexMethodAttribute. Since the tutorial only
provides an example for C#, I tried running PEX on the .exe without
any annotation. So I compiled my code in Visual Studio, got my
assembly light.exe and tried to run PEX on it. I got the following
error:

```
Microsoft Pex v0.94.51006.1 -- http://research.microsoft.com/pex --
v4.0.30319
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 2007-2010. All rights reserved.

unexpected error: error while loading of 'light' (currently running
with 4 bytes/pointer).
     LAUNCHER FAILED
unexpected failure: error while loading assembly (-1006 - 0xfffffc12)
```

So I have following questions:

1. Is it possible to use PEX with C? Or have I to convert my code to
   C#?
2. It looks like my light.exe is not a ".NET assembly". How do I
   produce a ".NET assembly" from C code?
3. Do I get the error message because my assembly is in the wrong format or
   because I didn't annotate the code? (second seems not likely to me because
   of the error message. I would expect something like "no explorations
   found after applying all filters; did you forget a [PexClass] or
   [PexMethod] attribute?").
4. If the error is not due to missing annotation or wrong format of
   the assembly, then what is the underlying cause?
5. How can I annotate a class with the PexClassAttribute in C++?
   Which libraries do I need and how does the process for producing an
   assembly work?

Comment: Your title refers to C, but the question is tagged C++. Which language are you concerned with? (It you're really asking about C++.)

Comment: Yes, actually I should have also tagged C, as I am interested in both languages.

Answer (score 3):

Pex only works on .NET assemblies. It *can* be used with any .NET language but C isn’t one – and even if it were then it would still only work on pure C code written to target the CLR, not on any native C code (which yours is).

So it doesn’t help that you’ve loaded your C code as a C++ project since even C++ code cannot be analysed by Pex unless it targets the CLR.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is probably me having no idea how
Visual Studio is supposed to work, but: How do I target my C++-code to CLR?

Comment: @user1646446 It’s not as easy as hitting a switch (although that too is involved, in the project options). You need to program a different dialect of C++, called [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI).